# Groovy: What is the difference between accessing a field with "this" and without it?

Tags: groovy, this

In my current project, I have encountered a rather counter-intuitive difference between accessing a field with `this` and without `this`. Apparently, if I access my field without `this`, for some reason, I get a boolean instead of the field I'm trying to access:

```
//Weapon extends Simple extends Entity extends Matter extends Object


@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
abstract class Action {
    Matter tool

    boolean setTool(Matter t) {
        if (isValidTool(t)) {
            tool = t
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    boolean isValidTool(Matter m) {
        return true
    }
}

@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
class Attack extends Action {

    boolean isValidTool(Matter m) {
        return (m instanceof Entity)
    }

    boolean setTool(Matter t) {
        if (isValidTool(t)) {
            if (t instanceof Weapon) {
                tool = t
            } else {
                tool = new ImprovisedWeapon((Entity)t)
                //ImprovisedWeapon extends Weapon
            }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    @Override
    Weapon getTool() {
        return (Weapon)this.tool
    }

    void test() {
        Weapon a = this.tool          //compile-time error
        Weapon b = (Weapon)this.tool  //works fine
        Weapon c = tool               //compile-time error
        Weapon d = (Weapon)tool       //compile-time error
    }
}
```

The errors I get, in order:

[Static type checking] - Cannot assign value of type project.matter.Matter to variable of type project.matter.simple.Weapon

[Static type checking] - Cannot assign value of type boolean to variable of type project.matter.simple.Weapon

[Static type checking] - Inconvertible types: cannot cast boolean to project.matter.simple.Weapon

The first error is explainable, I don't get to use `getTool()` after all, and instead effectively use `this.@tool`, which obviously returns a Matter. The other two errors, however, are very weird - no local variable `tool` is declared, the only `tool` around is the one inherited from `Action`, which is a `Matter`. The locally declared `getTool()` would even return a Weapon, and not a boolean. So, my question is, what exactly do I access here when I use `tool`, and why is it different from `this.tool`?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This might be better as a comment than an answer, but I don't have the reputation to comment.

I'm not sure why, but the error seems to have something to do with the return type of setTool. I think it might be more normal to have setters that don't return anything.

I've given this a try in a groovyConsole (groovy 2.2.1), and with your code (along with dummy classes for the missing ones), I experienced the last two errors that you see (not the first one). Once I set the return type of the setTool methods to void (and removed the return statements), those errors went away, but the first error then appeared for the third line (`Weapon c = tool`).

Unfortunately I can't explain why any of this is happening, but I hope it is of some help to you! Maybe someone else can give the reasoning behind the behaviour.

Comment: I'm still in 2.0.1 (the version in the latest NetBeans Release), so that might explain why the behaviour is different. This might indicate that this is perhaps not intended behaviour at all, but a bug that was fixed in later versions.